# Invert the left svg animation?

Tags: css, svg

Here is my code https://codepen.io/victoreugen2002/pen/PoJJPzP

I am trying to animate the left and right svg, to acheive this:

1. both starting at the same time from the top and they continue drawing.
2. until they both met at the bottom in the middle.

In order to acheive this I am thinking of inversing the animation for left svg, but it's not working:

```
.left {
    width: 50%;
    stroke-dasharray: 1855.968505859375;
    animation: dash 2s ease-in;

    @keyframes dash {
        from {
            stroke-dashoffset: 1855.968505859375;
        }
        to {
            stroke-dashoffset: 3710;
        }
    }

    svg {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You had to go from **-1855.968505859375** to **0**.

```css
.left {
  width: 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 1855.968505859375;
  animation: dash-left 2s ease-in;
}

.left svg {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 1855.968505859375;
  animation: dash-right 2s ease-in;
}

.right svg {
  right: 0;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}


@keyframes dash-left {
  from { stroke-dashoffset: -1855.968505859375 }
  to { stroke-dashoffset: 0 }
}

@keyframes dash-right {
  from { stroke-dashoffset: 1855.968505859375 }
  to { stroke-dashoffset: 0 }
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 733 425">
    <path d="M733,424.5H39A38.5,38.5,0,0,1,.5,386V39A38.5,38.5,0,0,1,39,.5H733" style="fill: none;stroke: #78be21"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 733 425">
    <path d="M0,.5H694A38.5,38.5,0,0,1,732.5,39V386A38.5,38.5,0,0,1,694,424.5H0" style="fill: none;stroke: #78be21"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```